# Growth index calculation R

Tags: r

Based on comments, I will adjust my question ad try to make it more understandable. Problem is still the same and show my way of calculating it currently. Here is shorter data with starting columns:

```
dput(my.df)
structure(list(date = structure(c(16831, 16860, 16891, 16921, 
16952, 16982, 17013, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17166, 17197, 
17225, 17256, 17286, 17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17439, 17470, 
17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651, 17682, 17712, 17743, 
17774, 17804), class = "Date"), price = c(98.67, 98.83, 100.07, 
100.11, 100.47, 100.63, 100.06, 100.14, 100.54, 100.8, 100.7, 
101.26, 100.39, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), fcst.yoy.growth = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.61, NA, NA, 
1.55, NA, NA, 1.58, NA, NA, 1.47, NA, NA, 1.37, NA, NA, 1.41, 
NA, NA, 1.51)), row.names = 194:226, class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"price", "fcst.yoy.growth"))
```

I have `price` index and future growth YoY forecasts. I want to solve price index for those future dates. I have been solving it as follows:

Create price index as far as there is lags in original price index and fill NAs from original:

```
my.df$growth1 <- (1+as.numeric(my.df$fcst.yoy.growth)/100) * as.numeric(lag(my.df$price, 12))
my.df$growth1[is.na(my.df$growth1)] <- my.df$price[is.na(my.df$growth1)]
```

Do the same thing again to get full results:

```
my.df$growth2 <- (1+as.numeric(my.df$fcst.yoy.growth)/100) * as.numeric(lag(my.df$growth1, 12))
my.df$growth2[is.na(my.df$growth2)] <- my.df$price[is.na(my.df$growth2)]
```

And growth2 is what I would like to get out.

Comment: Might be a problem with `class = c("xts", "zoo")`? Why don't you use `data.frame`? What is the expected output? `View(testdata)` throws `Error in View : cannot coerce class "c("xts", "zoo")" to a data.frame`

Comment: what's low_index? is it the prediction for cpi.xts?

Comment: low_index is prediction for cpi.xts. (Low, Mean High) are YoY growth forecasts for cpi.xts.

Comment: I can `View(testdata)` fine. expected output is 3 new columns, with forecasted cpi.xts (with those growth rates). I plan to interpolate NA from between, so no need to worry those.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: added result data (just realized it is data.frame not xts) but either one is fine for me.

Comment: I modified my question to attract response and solution.